# Font-family property on <nav>

Tags: html

Okay, I try to change the font-family inside the <nav> tag, and it won't change, I've tried another property of font, like font-weight, font-style, font-size, and It works, but font-family. Why the heck this is happened? I can't figure out.

This is the html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" media="screen">
    <title>One Piece | Petualangan Tiada Akhir</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <header>
            <hgroup>
                <h1>One Piece : Petualangan Tiada Akhir</h1>
                <h2>Luffy dan Kawan-Kawan Mugiwara Pirates</h2>
            </hgroup>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">beranda</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">daftar isi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">kontak</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">profil</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">privacy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">disclaimer</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section>
          <h2>Section</h2>
        </section>
        <footer>
           <small>&copy; Contoh Makalah Mahasiswa Font: Oswald, Source Sans Pro Powered by Blogger Template by :]</small>
        </footer>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

now the CSS :

```
*{
  font-family:calibri;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

header{
  padding:10px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  background-color:#0fcdcf;
}

header h1{
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:2.5em;
  font-family:Imprint MT Shadow;
}

header h2{
  font-size:1.5em;
  font-family:Giddyup Std;
}

nav{
  padding-top:10px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:0.9em;
  font-family:times new roman;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-style:normal;
 }

nav li{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin-right:5px;
  display:inline;
}

body{
  background-color:#d7d5e0;
}   

div{
  width:80%;    
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  box-shadow:10px 5px 10px #888888;
}

section{
  padding:10px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  background-color:white;
}

footer{
  padding:10px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  background-color:white;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Providing your code would help a lot.

Comment: You need to read up about css specificity: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FCSS%2FSpecificity&ei=HWhOVNfyGNTfsAT2goHoAw&usg=AFQjCNHG_f6LtVjuZJ7_0REyqI-uHMz0bQ&sig2=y4Kv2nipdBgKHIHpdSJhbA&bvm=bv.77880786,d.cWc

Comment: Have you tried quoting the font names, e.g. `font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;`?

Comment: It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'll try again :-) Have you tried putting quotes around the font name, e.g. `font-family: "Times New Roman";`. Additionally, which browser(s) are you testing in?

Comment: Yes, I have tried putting quotes, and my browser is IE 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make above example work, select a tag and change font-name it works, I guess to apply font family some text should be present in that element

```
nav li a{
    font-family:arial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should show your code.
Anyways, this should work:

```
<nav style="font-family: xxx;">
```